# java spring send mime message with plain text and hyper link, plain text is not shown in email

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send an mime email with both plain text and a hyper link. The email is sent successfully, but only the hyper link part is shown, the plan text is not shown. My codes are:

```
 MimeMessage message = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage(); 
        MimeMessageHelper helper;

        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");

            //helper.setText("please click below link to activate your account and further processiong","<html><a href="+link+">plase Click</a></html>");   
            //message.setContent("haha", "text/html");
            helper.setSubject("Hello");
            helper.setText("please click below link reset your passowrd","<html><a href="+link+">plase Click</a></html>");
            helper.setFrom("zeng8211626@163.com");
            helper.setTo("zeng8211626@163.com");
        } catch (MessagingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {  
            this.mailSender.send(message);; 
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            returnCode = 99;
        }
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Notice: `helper.setText()` takes 2 parameters, `String text` and `boolean html`, you need do this:

```
helper.setText("your text", true)
```

Comment: I use helper.setText(plainText, htmlText)
should plain text be my plain text and htmlText be the link?

if I use helper.setText("your text", true), where should the plain text go?

Comment: @user2053760 before u call a method, you should read the javadoc, the method `helper.setText(String,String) says: `Set the given plain text and HTML text as alternatives, offering both options to the email client.`

Comment: @user2053760 by the way it requires multipart mode

Comment: If I want both plain text and link shown in the email, what should I do?

Comment: I did something like:
helper.setText("please click below link reset your passowrd", false);
helper.setText("<a href="+link+">plase Click</a>", true);
but it does not work.

Comment: @user2053760 you need save your message and open it with a text editor, you should see info of the message, like if it is a multipart msg, maybe it just now shown, it is there.. because spring by default using  `MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED`, it sounds like it will show the msg relatively

Answer (score 1):

**From Docs:**
If you want to set only html , use

```
helper.setText(String htmlText, true);
```

If you want to set both html and plaintext use

```
helper.setText(String plainText, String htmlText);
```